# Web Api 2: BadRequest with custom error model

Tags: c#, rest, asp.net-web-api, asp.net-web-api2

The `BadRequest` method available on `ApiController` only accepts a string:

```
// Summary:
//     Creates an System.Web.Http.Results.ErrorMessageResult (400 Bad Request) with
//     the specified error message.
//
// Parameters:
//   message:
//     The user-visible error message.
//
// Returns:
//     An System.Web.Http.Results.InvalidModelStateResult with the specified model
//     state.
protected internal virtual BadRequestErrorMessageResult BadRequest(string message);
```

**Why is there no overload which accepts an custom error model T?**

For example, I might want to return a code along with the message:

```
{
    message: "Error message",
    code: "1000",
}
```

I could just do the following but I suspect there must be an underlying reason (perhaps in accordance with RESTful standards?):

```
return Content(HttpStatusCode.BadRequest, errorModel);
```

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Not sure if this is still relevant, as the question is more than 2 years old...
Still, the way to do it is indeed using

```
return Content(HttpStatusCode.BadRequest, errorModel);
```

Having a standardized model for errors to include detailed information is actually a pretty good practice. See also here: [API Best Practices: Response Handling](https://blogs.mulesoft.com/dev/api-dev/api-best-practices-response-handling/)